# Websphere 7 - 404 when not including trailing slash in url

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I am working on a project using Spring 4 MVC, AngularJS, and Websphere 7. When I build my application as a war and install it through the Websphere 7 admin console everything works fine. However, I need my war wrapped in an EAR (not the generic EAR that websphere automatically wraps it in). So I created a seperate project that takes the WAR and wraps it in an EAR.

When I go to the url `http://localhost:9080/public/myapp` then I get a 404 that it can't find the resources. When I add a trailing slash on it like this `http://localhost:9080/public/myapp/` then it redirects to the `index.html` resource just fine. I need it to find the `index.html` when I go to the url without the trailing slash. How can I get that to work?

Here's my configuration files:

**application.xml in the EAR**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">
  <display-name>myapp-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>myapp-web-2.0-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/public/myapp</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

**ibm-web-bnd.xml in the WAR**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-bnd xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_0.xsd"
         version="1.0">

    <virtual-host name="default_host"/>

    <resource-ref name="UwProfileDataSource" binding-name="jdbc/uwprofile"></resource-ref>
</web-bnd>
```

**web.xml in the WAR**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>myapp Service</description>
        <res-ref-name>UwProfileDataSource</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>

</web-app>
```

**myapp-servlet.xml in the WAR**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="classpath:/app/"/>
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="forward:/index.html" />


    <bean id="uwProfileDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName"><value>UwProfileDataSource</value></property>
        <property name="resourceRef"><value>true</value></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Do you manually map the URLs during deployment or have you got them defined in application.xml?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I've got them in the EAR file, I'll go ahead and post my ibm-web-bnd.xml from the webinf folder of the WAR and also the application.xml in the EAR.

Comment: Does it work when you access it through IHS?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I don't have any experience with IHS. But the app itself is working fine, I just need the trailing slash to go away. It's a requirement because many other apps in our portal point to that URL location.

Comment: Best practice is to have IHS/Apache HTTPd in front of your application server; IHS/Apache will usually take care of this

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack since this is an enterprise application that is being deployed to servers that have been around for a long time, I'd like to avoid having to change those server configurations too much. Is there some way I can configure the EAR to redirect from the URL without the trailing slash to the URL with the trailing slash?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Accidentally clicked on the move discussion to chat link, please ignore that if you got notified. But websphere seems to do the redirect fine when I install the war through the console and it gets wrapped in an auto-generated ear made by websphere. So theres got to be some sort of configuration going on there that I'm missing in my own ear.

Comment: The metadata the wrapped EAR creates for the standalone WAR may give you some data to pattern off of for the WAR. How about making your WAR context root /public/ and putting a url-pattern of "/myapp" in the web.xml?

Comment: @ewhoch I tried that and a few other configurations with no luck. I'm going to take a look at the metadata of the auto-generated EAR compared to my custom EAR and see If i can find the solution. If you have any other suggestions I'm open to them.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Is this issue of URL rewriting resolved? I need to set my web.xml to redirect requests to index.html in a subfolder. My app is currently breaking with 404 error. Can someone share a currect configuration?